# Getting HTML elements using requests and BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, python-requests

Good evening guys.
I'm trying to get some html elements using requests and BeautifulSoup. Using the request's content as an argument to the parser, I'd like to get the final quotation in a stock prices historic website. This information is stored in the class "quotes-table-result__val" in this link (https://iqoption.com/pt/historical-financial-quotes?active_id=1&tz_offset=-180&date=2017-3-4-0-0). However, the script is returning a None object. Do you know what I'm doing wrong?

Code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

r = requests.get('https://iqoption.com/pt/historical-financial-quotes?active_id=1&tz_offset=-180&date=2017-3-4-0-0')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html5lib')
final_quotation = soup.find(class_='quotes-table-result__val')
```

Answer (score 0):

Notice that when you search for a given history this website requests a `GET` method, and after that request is complete the data on the table is loaded.

You will have to simulate the request and parse the results. For what I've seen the request method will return a json object.

Please notice the **date** parameter in the request. You'll have your desired date there.

Learn more about `requests` and `json parsing` [here](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#json-response-content).

Here is an example code:

```
import requests

r = requests.get('https://eu.iqoption.com/api/quote/history/v1/expirations?active_id=1&tz_offset=-180&date=2017-3-4-0-0')
JSON_OBJECT = r.json()

for datetime_object in JSON_OBJECT["result"]["expirations"]:
    Bid = datetime_object["bid"]
    Ask = datetime_object["ask"]
    Value = datetime_object["value"]

    print ("DateTime: %s - Bid (%s) - Ask (%s) - Value (%s)" % (datetime_object["datetime"], Bid, Ask, Value))
```

Which outputs:

> DateTime: 2017-03-04 00:00:00 - Bid (1.06241) - Ask (1.06224) - Value (1.062325)
>
> DateTime: 2017-03-04 00:00:01 - Bid (1.06241) - Ask (1.06224) - Value (1.062325)
>
> DateTime: 2017-03-04 00:00:02 - Bid (1.06241) - Ask (1.06224) - Value (1.062325)
>
> ...

Comment: Is there a way to do that with BeautifulSoup?

Comment: Beautifulsoup is not prepared ro handle json.